# PNG with transparent background shows black on older iPads

Tags: ios, ipad, png

I have a bug in my iPad app that is driving me crazy. The app allows users to drop clipart onto pages. The clipart images are PNG with transparent backgrounds. I create a simple UIImageView and set opaque to NO. In all my testing, everything works perfectly. However, it seems that people with older iPads (maybe iPad 2?) these images have black backgrounds. It doesn't appear to be an issue with the iOS, but it appears to be an issue with the iPad.

Website where you can see 90-95% of the clipart images are perfectly fine, while 5-10% have the black backgrounds: http://www.printpad.com

Code I am using for the UIImageView:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:resized imageBorderColor:borderColor imageBorderWidth:borderWidth];
[imageView.layer setOpaque:NO];
imageView.opaque = NO;
imageView.frame = rect;
[view addSubview:imageView];
```

I really hope someone out there has encountered this and can help, as I can't even think of how to debug or anything. Thanks!!!!!

EDIT: The original image is downloaded into the Documents directory, and then it is resized like this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
CGSize newSize = [MyUtility getNewSize:image.size maximumSize:CGSizeMake(200, 200)];
UIImage *resized = [UIImage imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:newSize];
```

Here is the imageWithImage category:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    [self beginImageContextWithSize:newSize];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [self endImageContext];
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Sure it's not the OS version? An older iPad is likely to run an older iOS. (If it really is specific to the hardware, it may have something to do with the hardware acceleration capabilities, though it seems unlikely).

Comment: Show the code that creates `resized`.

Comment: This is quite likely to be an issue with PNGs getting converted to JPEG. Watch out with `UIImage`, if you don't control what's going on under the hood, it may be preferring jpeg image representations when they are available. You should also check and update your question with better info which iPad models and which iOS versions. + as Nikolai says, show us the code route from your 'raw' png to your 'resized' image.

Comment: I will try to trace down what iPads and iOS versions are having the problem, however it is very difficult because I don't own any of the devices that have the problem, and there have only been a couple people that have actually emailed me. I know there are more people out there with the problem because the app allows them to upload the books they create and I can see some images with the black backgrounds in their screenshots. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: `-[UIImage imageWithImage:scaledToSize:]` is not a framework method. Post the code of this method.

Answer (score 0):

As with the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23355129/1751266

Is it possible that you're creating the image as opaque instead of transparent? If you're using UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions or similar then the second parameter should be NO.